# CSS to make line items text wrap

Tags: html, css

How can I extend the vertical size of a `<li>` when text wrapping is required, but keep a minimum value?

[image]

The look of this is exactly what I want when the text is short enough to fit on one line. But if the text is longer (I'm not expecting more than 2 lines), it gets cut.

My HTML looks like this:

```css
.items {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
}

.items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 0.2em;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .3em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  height: 1.6em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.items li.test {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.items .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
  top: -4px;
  height: 1.8em;
  margin-right: .8em;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="test">
    <span class="badge">0</span>
    This is a long string that doesnt fit on one line.
    Need to extend this box vertically
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    <span class="badge">0</span>
    Next item
  </li>
</ul>
```

My problem with changing `.items li { height: 1.6em; }` to `max-height` is I end up with this:

[image]

I don't mind the messed up long string, but the height of the second `<li>` is now larger.

Comment: I think you just need to remove the height assignment: `height: 1.6em;`

Comment: Remove `height: 1.6em;` and your `li` height will be according to the content.

Comment: The only problem is that if I do that, the `<li>` is too short for the single-line case.

Comment: So the question was slightly more complicated, due to a `<span>` in the `<li>`,  updated.

Comment: Solved that in the `<span>` by deleting `display: inline-block` and adjusting the `left:` and `top:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping `height` for `min-height`:

```css
.items {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
}

.items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 0.2em;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .3em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  min-height: 1.6em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.items li.test {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="test">
    This is a long string that doesnt fit on one line.
    Need to extend this box vertically
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    Next item
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Update:**

To account for your follow-up comment: Since you're using a padding on the `<li>` element and you want the badge to occupy the full height without using `position: absolute`, remove the explicit `height` declaration from the badge and `top: -4px` and use negative margins instead:

```css
.items {
  width: 20em;
  
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  
  list-style-type: none;
}

.items li {
  min-height: 1.6em;
  
  position: relative;
  left: 0.2em;
  margin: .3em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  
  background-color: #EEE;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}

.items li.test {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.items .badge {
  color: white;
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 1em;
  
  width: 2em;
  
  display: inline-block;
  
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-right: .8em;
  padding: 0.8em 0.7em;
  
  background-color: #607D8B;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="test">
    <span class="badge">0</span> This is a long string that doesnt fit on one line. Need to extend this box vertically
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    <span class="badge">0</span> Next item
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yep that works. 

One more followup:  I do have a styled button in this `<li>` which should be the same height as the `<li>`.  If I replace `height` with `min-height`, the `<li>` becomes larger than the button.

Comment: Hey, @Stewart. Check out my edit for a way to make the badge occupy the full height of the `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `li` is too short for single-line cases, then `min-height` should do it (instead of `height`). The element will take up a minimal height that you set and might expand if needed.

```css
.items {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
}

.items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 0.2em;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .3em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  min-height: 1.6em;
  /* Change this */
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.items li.test {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="test">
    This is a long string that doesnt fit on one line. Need to extend this box vertically that is really something something something.
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    This is a long string that doesnt fit on one line. Need to extend this box vertically
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    Next item
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.items {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
}

.items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 0.2em;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .3em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  min-height: 1.6em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.items li.test {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="test">
    This is a long string that doesnt fit on one line.
    Need to extend this box vertically
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    Next item
  </li>
</ul>
```